# Debugging "max pool size was reached"

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, connection-pooling

I am trying to figure out whats causing the pool size to reach its max connection, I want to verify if it's a leak.

I verified all my connections are wrapped with a `using` block, for example :

```
public static async Task<Int32> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(String commandText, params MySqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(m_ConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {   
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            if (parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }

            conn.Open();
            return await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I added a diagnose log in case of max pool size reached:

```
public static void PrintPoolSize()
{
    try
    {
        Assembly ms = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MySql.Data.dll"));// Assembly.LoadFrom("MySql.Data.dll");
        Type type = ms.GetType("MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager");
        MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("GetPool", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var pool = mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(strConnectionString) });
        PropertyInfo pInfo = pool.GetType().GetProperty("NumConnections",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var poolNumConnectionsCount = pInfo.GetValue(pool, null);

        var maxPoolSize = pool.GetType().GetFields(
                 BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                 BindingFlags.Instance).Where(i => i.Name == "maxSize").Select(i => i.GetValue(pool)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        s_logger.Info(string.Format("PrintPoolSize->openConnections={0} / maxPoolSize={1}", poolNumConnectionsCount, maxPoolSize));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        s_logger.Error("PrintPoolSize: got exc; ", ex);
    }
}
```

And I see i have reached 100/100 connection.

What I want to do next is to print all the open connections(SQL queries?) in a current point of time, is that possible? if not so how should I move forward with my diagnostic?

It takes my system a couple of days/weeks to reach the max pool size, its not immediate.

I am using `MySql.Data.MySQLClient` with a `MaxPoolSize` of 100.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do it from MySql-side via a tool rather than via code?  That's the best way to monitor connections.  BTW, what's with the late-bound reflection calls to `MySqlPoolManager`?

Comment: @MickyD not so simple has this is a cloud DB which servers multiple applications

Comment: "I verified all my connections are wrapped with a using block" -- when I've debugged similar problems, it usually turns out that one connection's been missed, and it's causing the problem. 
You could switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ and use its debug-level logging to troubleshoot this problem in detail (without reflection): https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/logging/